# Two Questions about Gamma Function Terminology

Tags: special-functions, factorial, gamma-function

Gamma function is also known as generalized factorial function .

**1.** Why does the term "generalized" have been used?

**2.** Why is the Gamma function called  Euler's second integral?

Comment: generalized means that the gamma functions extends the factorial funcion ($\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$)... this is the kind of questions that can be answered perfectly by wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) is defined only for integers:
$$
n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1
$$
The [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\Gamma(x)$, is defined for general complex arguments
$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}\,e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
where the integral converges if $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt0$, but $\Gamma(x)$ can be [analytically continued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) to the whole complex plane minus some isolated points using the reflection formula: 
$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi z)}
$$

$\Gamma(x)$ is called the generalized factorial since $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$.

The [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the Gamma function are called [Euler's first and second integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_integral).

Comment: You're welcome. Was anything left unanswered?

Comment: is there difference between Γ(z) & Γ(x) ?

Comment: No, $z$ is often used to indicate a complex variable and $x$ a real variable.